# Laravel json api to webapp

Tags: php, json, laravel

I've build an api for 2 apps. Now I want to build a webapp but how should I parse the output to an object? `json_decode` is not working!?

In postman this is the response I receive:

```
    {
  "company": [
    [
      {
        "CompanyName": "Weimann-Watsica",
        "Logo": "/tmp/7a23ae584c52f3ab351e89bff25ce3eb.jpg",
        "Address": "108 Turcotte Lane Suite 292\nMyatown, VA 65405",
        "Zip": "98604-",
        "City": "Craigview",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "abc8db0e-847e-343c-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Schuster-Harber",
        "Logo": "/tmp/11ab2217784143c2f8633ee36979bc2e.jpg",
        "Address": "98050 Green Circle Apt. 773\nKassulkefort, SC 17967",
        "Zip": "12712-",
        "City": "Granvilleborough",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "ad805e0a-fc5b-381e-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Considine and Sons",
        "Logo": "/tmp/3ad1fd539790a26731efa58fc6aa60d3.jpg",
        "Address": "8456 Nick Road\nEast Kaseyborough, KY 51166",
        "Zip": "24489-",
        "City": "Langworthbury",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "c6676f89-b18b-3c29-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Franecki Group",
        "Logo": "/tmp/22c955f9ffbfb7ff9c5815be4bdc285a.jpg",
        "Address": "5862 Lindsey Islands\nGusikowskistad, IL 93018",
        "Zip": "75074-",
        "City": "Denesikmouth",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "73003d6e-980e-3b5a-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Haley, Funk and Prosacco",
        "Logo": "/tmp/673faaa8f27ebf429ad3fd2233433f66.jpg",
        "Address": "410 Watsica Place Apt. 189\nEast Draketon, WV 43417-8899",
        "Zip": "88619",
        "City": "Cassinville",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "bb13a773-13d1-3e45-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Littel Ltd",
        "Logo": "/tmp/48af3b908f843b84aa16184c6c785ff4.jpg",
        "Address": "30658 Leopold Squares Suite 278\nLake Otiliafurt, AZ 63970",
        "Zip": "71925",
        "City": "Lake Lerahaven",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "ddc14688-8a61-3278-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Padberg-Schinner",
        "Logo": "/tmp/f4c83766297f0a3644cbbbfc3c6abf07.jpg",
        "Address": "247 Amani Mountains\nLake Erwin, NJ 63657-4632",
        "Zip": "89299",
        "City": "West Merl",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "6ba1be4e-0faf-3faf-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Gaylord PLC",
        "Logo": "/tmp/6ae6de23a4a0aa41aae8dea7c7e7910c.jpg",
        "Address": "479 Conrad Wells\nWest Earl, UT 70491-6540",
        "Zip": "83609-",
        "City": "Schusterfurt",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "7630d83a-b16d-3d2c-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "O'Hara-Witting",
        "Logo": "/tmp/3f250a95fe2939295b96900c49f0e24b.jpg",
        "Address": "001 Evert Well\nShyanneport, UT 69785-4429",
        "Zip": "49353",
        "City": "Port Aleenburgh",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "25ee832a-aca5-3c53-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Cormier and Sons",
        "Logo": "/tmp/e67e1ae47e2659ee25bea28b6832a974.jpg",
        "Address": "5130 Spinka Vista Apt. 888\nWest Carissamouth, ID 48028-9281",
        "Zip": "50161",
        "City": "Lake Loyhaven",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "a2886d81-1bbd-34cf-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Johnston, Stracke and Hyatt",
        "Logo": "/tmp/355efcb5fd1070d5ae12d50d07b92804.jpg",
        "Address": "74364 Cheyenne Mall\nWest Tysonfort, DE 19649",
        "Zip": "00872-",
        "City": "Schambergerview",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "0f90c863-2997-37a4-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Mann-Little",
        "Logo": "/tmp/772c54749e18028a571a344d1ce8ecb0.jpg",
        "Address": "2816 Elisha Canyon\nNew Rhett, NJ 06711",
        "Zip": "02541",
        "City": "Kiehnberg",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "bc2eb9e9-764c-3427-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Koelpin LLC",
        "Logo": "/tmp/d71bdd9f4180e3ef2ac78ca1d8f4c544.jpg",
        "Address": "83328 Robb Gardens\nNew Alannaburgh, OH 82265-4451",
        "Zip": "91119-",
        "City": "Terryside",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "94c2969e-1080-3e4b-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Hettinger-Koepp",
        "Logo": "/tmp/ba956219f80d557ccce96e7904a8b98f.jpg",
        "Address": "368 Jacobs Road\nDylanside, CT 29936",
        "Zip": "84392",
        "City": "Kaylahtown",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "616dca15-8f8c-307d-b"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Bartell-Heathcote",
        "Logo": "/tmp/23a34d152c7c9972f787c61829c7a348.jpg",
        "Address": "98939 Borer Loaf\nWest Augustine, WY 98256",
        "Zip": "16916-",
        "City": "Leuschketown",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "4e0b237b-9841-3052-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Crist, Prohaska and Pacocha",
        "Logo": "/tmp/53d1c7eb7dd16b1d1a9ec0a7019b990f.jpg",
        "Address": "97779 Grant Stravenue Apt. 753\nLake Coty, AK 67959-9158",
        "Zip": "70297-",
        "City": "Port Lelia",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "d612fe06-a438-32c8-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Leuschke, Rice and Quigley",
        "Logo": "/tmp/b2e5e7c7dedf630934de260ffacaeab5.jpg",
        "Address": "13475 Nitzsche Lodge\nAlysaside, MT 85057",
        "Zip": "24897",
        "City": "East Bernice",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "1d160d74-6d1d-3d0d-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Champlin Ltd",
        "Logo": "/tmp/e08399803fbbc3b361ca09942af5fc30.jpg",
        "Address": "1864 Baumbach Dam\nPort Joeyborough, VT 04166-1913",
        "Zip": "83480-",
        "City": "New Alana",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "626f6b9c-2681-3ad9-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Hilpert Group",
        "Logo": "/tmp/aa142bb879e8a03df8634e87cb2e5f5e.jpg",
        "Address": "9193 Funk Alley\nMcCluretown, MO 03610-2601",
        "Zip": "32091",
        "City": "New Karentown",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "ec29c579-f6de-3d58-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Conroy-McKenzie",
        "Logo": "/tmp/275dac535cb9ce031faee19309363ad5.jpg",
        "Address": "906 Shirley Wall Suite 397\nO'Reillyfort, AL 85503-2410",
        "Zip": "49532-",
        "City": "Lake Oletaport",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "39dad66c-e399-319a-b"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Kris, Schoen and Orn",
        "Logo": "/tmp/9ca37b175c49e2a786afc747659d91c9.jpg",
        "Address": "41106 Amelia Locks\nLavinaburgh, DC 59553",
        "Zip": "75767",
        "City": "South Melyssaside",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "115e3932-12b4-3fb4-b"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Zemlak, Wuckert and Rosenbaum",
        "Logo": "/tmp/635c51a3cc0de11289c2997a8eba0347.jpg",
        "Address": "99847 Stiedemann Estates Suite 623\nWest Korymouth, HI 41991-1801",
        "Zip": "61771",
        "City": "Justicebury",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "9f2a79b9-b353-3c09-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Bogisich, Stokes and O'Conner",
        "Logo": "/tmp/37f259657a82c06a96affba1ac8f7940.jpg",
        "Address": "240 Mariane Rapid\nWest Effie, WA 73757-8372",
        "Zip": "26105",
        "City": "Port Caden",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "f27b4b43-d964-3ef0-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Swift and Sons",
        "Logo": "/tmp/28b2223c1bb990dfb0a072054f900a9d.jpg",
        "Address": "318 Maybelle Turnpike\nSchaefermouth, OK 59036",
        "Zip": "44838",
        "City": "Homenickmouth",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "3ce903d4-10b3-3c9d-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Gleichner, Mosciski and Donnelly",
        "Logo": "/tmp/fd7e0af605193766fc1f1da598886f49.jpg",
        "Address": "922 Dariana Club Apt. 822\nEast Mireille, NY 88400-0249",
        "Zip": "89335-",
        "City": "Hortensefort",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "05b2ed89-3568-3478-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Schiller-Conroy",
        "Logo": "/tmp/37ad9c0d3946b50668e916ed7e5192a0.jpg",
        "Address": "4251 Mariah Knoll\nPort Shanelburgh, MT 37153-6153",
        "Zip": "37923",
        "City": "Ronaldochester",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "058cd122-60e3-31fd-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Cartwright, Sanford and Morar",
        "Logo": "/tmp/cb9804f1dd41bfe137255a3fefd0264d.jpg",
        "Address": "204 Grover Roads Suite 203\nLake Hailee, HI 24534-2955",
        "Zip": "85590-",
        "City": "Ronside",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "cdc49e99-fb43-31e0-9"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

When I try:

```
$companies = $this->company->showCompanies();
dd($companies);
```

Result is:

```
JsonResponse {#230 ▼
  #jsonOptions: 0
  #data: "{"company":[[{"CompanyName":"Weimann-Watsica","Logo":"\/tmp\/7a23ae584c52f3ab351e89bff25ce3eb.jpg","Address":"108 Turcotte Lane Suite 292\nMyatown, VA 65405","Zip":"98604-","City":"Craigview","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"abc8db0e-847e-343c-9"},{"CompanyName":"Schuster-Harber","Logo":"\/tmp\/11ab2217784143c2f8633ee36979bc2e.jpg","Address":"98050 Green Circle Apt. 773\nKassulkefort, SC 17967","Zip":"12712-","City":"Granvilleborough","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"ad805e0a-fc5b-381e-9"},{"CompanyName":"Considine and Sons","Logo":"\/tmp\/3ad1fd539790a26731efa58fc6aa60d3.jpg","Address":"8456 Nick Road\nEast Kaseyborough, KY 51166","Zip":"24489-","City":"Langworthbury","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"c6676f89-b18b-3c29-9"},{"CompanyName":"Franecki Group","Logo":"\/tmp\/22c955f9ffbfb7ff9c5815be4bdc285a.jpg","Address":"5862 Lindsey Islands\nGusikowskistad, IL 93018","Zip":"75074-","City":"Denesikmouth","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"73003d6e-980e-3b5a-9"},{"CompanyName":"Haley, Funk and Prosacco","Logo":"\/tmp\/673faaa8f27ebf429ad3fd2233433f66.jpg","Address":"410 Watsica Place Apt. 189\nEast Draketon, WV 43417-8899","Zip":"88619","City":"Cassinville","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"bb13a773-13d1-3e45-9"},{"CompanyName":"Littel Ltd","Logo":"\/tmp\/48af3b908f843b84aa16184c6c785ff4.jpg","Address":"30658 Leopold Squares Suite 278\nLake Otiliafurt, AZ 63970","Zip":"71925","City":"Lake Lerahaven","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"ddc14688-8a61-3278-8"},{"CompanyName":"Padberg-Schinner","Logo":"\/tmp\/f4c83766297f0a3644cbbbfc3c6abf07.jpg","Address":"247 Amani Mountains\nLake Erwin, NJ 63657-4632","Zip":"89299","City":"West Merl","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"6ba1be4e-0faf-3faf-8"},{"CompanyName":"Gaylord PLC","Logo":"\/tmp\/6ae6de23a4a0aa41aae8dea7c7e7910c.jpg","Address":"479 Conrad Wells\nWest Earl, UT 70491-6540","Zip":"83609-","City":"Schusterfurt","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"7630d83a-b16d-3d2c-a"},{"CompanyName":"O'Hara-Witting","Logo":"\/tmp\/3f250a95fe2939295b96900c49f0e24b.jpg","Address":"001 Evert Well\nShyanneport, UT 69785-4429","Zip":"49353","City":"Port Aleenburgh","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"25ee832a-aca5-3c53-a"},{"CompanyName":"Cormier and Sons","Logo":"\/tmp\/e67e1ae47e2659ee25bea28b6832a974.jpg","Address":"5130 Spinka Vista Apt. 888\nWest Carissamouth, ID 48028-9281","Zip":"50161","City":"Lake Loyhaven","KvkNumber":null,"EcaboNumber":"a2886d81-1bbd-34cf-8"},{"CompanyName":"Johnston, Stracke and Hyatt","Logo":"\/tmp\/355efcb5fd1070d5ae12d50d07b92804.jpg"
```

When I try:

```
$companies = $this->company->showCompanies();
dd(json_decode($companies));
```

Result is null?

What should I do?
(it's dummy data)

Comment: Did you `dd` just the `$companies` variable? I bet the result is decoded already.

Comment: It's not decoded! Added the result to my question.

Comment: You're supposed to put a json-encoded string into `json_decode`. You're feeding it an object. Try `dd(json_decode($companies->data))`. Alternatively try dumping `get_class($companies)` to let us know the FQCN (looks like a Symfony JsonResponse)

Comment: @Denker the result of get_class($companies) is "Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse" when I do json_decode($companies->data) result is: Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::$data

Comment: use `$companies->getData()` instead of `json_decode($companies)` :) You can always refer to the [Laravel API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html) or just pop open the class and look inside it.

Answer (score 2):

I see wrong `json` format:

```
$dummy = '{
"company": [
    [{
        "CompanyName": "Weimann-Watsica",
        "Logo": "/tmp/7a23ae584c52f3ab351e89bff25ce3eb.jpg",
        "Address": "108 Turcotte Lane Suite 292\nMyatown, VA 65405",
        "Zip": "98604-",
        "City": "Craigview",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "abc8db0e-847e-343c-9"
    }, {
        "CompanyName": "Schuster-Harber",
        "Logo": "/tmp/11ab2217784143c2f8633ee36979bc2e.jpg",
        "Address": "98050 Green Circle Apt. 773\nKassulkefort, SC 17967",
        "Zip": "12712-",
        "City": "Granvilleborough",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "ad805e0a-fc5b-381e-9"
    }, {
        "CompanyName": "Considine and Sons",
        "Logo": "/tmp/3ad1fd539790a26731efa58fc6aa60d3.jpg",
        "Address": "8456 Nick Road\nEast Kaseyborough, KY 51166",
        "Zip": "24489-",
        "City": "Langworthbury",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "c6676f89-b18b-3c29-9"
    }, {
        "CompanyName": "Franecki Group",
        "Logo": "/tmp/22c955f9ffbfb7ff9c5815be4bdc285a.jpg",
        "Address": "5862 Lindsey Islands\nGusikowskistad, IL 93018",
        "Zip": "75074-",
        "City": "Denesikmouth",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "73003d6e-980e-3b5a-9"
    }]
]
}';
          $companies = json_decode($dummy);
          dd($companies);
```

**Edit**: you edit your `json` and I'm getting -2, anyway, this code working:

```
$dummy = '{


 "company": [
    [
      {
        "CompanyName": "Weimann-Watsica",
        "Logo": "/tmp/7a23ae584c52f3ab351e89bff25ce3eb.jpg",
        "Address": "108 Turcotte Lane Suite 292\nMyatown, VA 65405",
        "Zip": "98604-",
        "City": "Craigview",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "abc8db0e-847e-343c-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Schuster-Harber",
        "Logo": "/tmp/11ab2217784143c2f8633ee36979bc2e.jpg",
        "Address": "98050 Green Circle Apt. 773\nKassulkefort, SC 17967",
        "Zip": "12712-",
        "City": "Granvilleborough",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "ad805e0a-fc5b-381e-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Considine and Sons",
        "Logo": "/tmp/3ad1fd539790a26731efa58fc6aa60d3.jpg",
        "Address": "8456 Nick Road\nEast Kaseyborough, KY 51166",
        "Zip": "24489-",
        "City": "Langworthbury",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "c6676f89-b18b-3c29-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Franecki Group",
        "Logo": "/tmp/22c955f9ffbfb7ff9c5815be4bdc285a.jpg",
        "Address": "5862 Lindsey Islands\nGusikowskistad, IL 93018",
        "Zip": "75074-",
        "City": "Denesikmouth",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "73003d6e-980e-3b5a-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Haley, Funk and Prosacco",
        "Logo": "/tmp/673faaa8f27ebf429ad3fd2233433f66.jpg",
        "Address": "410 Watsica Place Apt. 189\nEast Draketon, WV 43417-8899",
        "Zip": "88619",
        "City": "Cassinville",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "bb13a773-13d1-3e45-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Littel Ltd",
        "Logo": "/tmp/48af3b908f843b84aa16184c6c785ff4.jpg",
        "Address": "30658 Leopold Squares Suite 278\nLake Otiliafurt, AZ 63970",
        "Zip": "71925",
        "City": "Lake Lerahaven",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "ddc14688-8a61-3278-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Padberg-Schinner",
        "Logo": "/tmp/f4c83766297f0a3644cbbbfc3c6abf07.jpg",
        "Address": "247 Amani Mountains\nLake Erwin, NJ 63657-4632",
        "Zip": "89299",
        "City": "West Merl",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "6ba1be4e-0faf-3faf-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Gaylord PLC",
        "Logo": "/tmp/6ae6de23a4a0aa41aae8dea7c7e7910c.jpg",
        "Address": "479 Conrad Wells\nWest Earl, UT 70491-6540",
        "Zip": "83609-",
        "City": "Schusterfurt",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "7630d83a-b16d-3d2c-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "O\'Hara-Witting",
        "Logo": "/tmp/3f250a95fe2939295b96900c49f0e24b.jpg",
        "Address": "001 Evert Well\nShyanneport, UT 69785-4429",
        "Zip": "49353",
        "City": "Port Aleenburgh",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "25ee832a-aca5-3c53-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Cormier and Sons",
        "Logo": "/tmp/e67e1ae47e2659ee25bea28b6832a974.jpg",
        "Address": "5130 Spinka Vista Apt. 888\nWest Carissamouth, ID 48028-9281",
        "Zip": "50161",
        "City": "Lake Loyhaven",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "a2886d81-1bbd-34cf-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Johnston, Stracke and Hyatt",
        "Logo": "/tmp/355efcb5fd1070d5ae12d50d07b92804.jpg",
        "Address": "74364 Cheyenne Mall\nWest Tysonfort, DE 19649",
        "Zip": "00872-",
        "City": "Schambergerview",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "0f90c863-2997-37a4-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Mann-Little",
        "Logo": "/tmp/772c54749e18028a571a344d1ce8ecb0.jpg",
        "Address": "2816 Elisha Canyon\nNew Rhett, NJ 06711",
        "Zip": "02541",
        "City": "Kiehnberg",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "bc2eb9e9-764c-3427-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Koelpin LLC",
        "Logo": "/tmp/d71bdd9f4180e3ef2ac78ca1d8f4c544.jpg",
        "Address": "83328 Robb Gardens\nNew Alannaburgh, OH 82265-4451",
        "Zip": "91119-",
        "City": "Terryside",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "94c2969e-1080-3e4b-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Hettinger-Koepp",
        "Logo": "/tmp/ba956219f80d557ccce96e7904a8b98f.jpg",
        "Address": "368 Jacobs Road\nDylanside, CT 29936",
        "Zip": "84392",
        "City": "Kaylahtown",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "616dca15-8f8c-307d-b"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Bartell-Heathcote",
        "Logo": "/tmp/23a34d152c7c9972f787c61829c7a348.jpg",
        "Address": "98939 Borer Loaf\nWest Augustine, WY 98256",
        "Zip": "16916-",
        "City": "Leuschketown",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "4e0b237b-9841-3052-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Crist, Prohaska and Pacocha",
        "Logo": "/tmp/53d1c7eb7dd16b1d1a9ec0a7019b990f.jpg",
        "Address": "97779 Grant Stravenue Apt. 753\nLake Coty, AK 67959-9158",
        "Zip": "70297-",
        "City": "Port Lelia",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "d612fe06-a438-32c8-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Leuschke, Rice and Quigley",
        "Logo": "/tmp/b2e5e7c7dedf630934de260ffacaeab5.jpg",
        "Address": "13475 Nitzsche Lodge\nAlysaside, MT 85057",
        "Zip": "24897",
        "City": "East Bernice",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "1d160d74-6d1d-3d0d-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Champlin Ltd",
        "Logo": "/tmp/e08399803fbbc3b361ca09942af5fc30.jpg",
        "Address": "1864 Baumbach Dam\nPort Joeyborough, VT 04166-1913",
        "Zip": "83480-",
        "City": "New Alana",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "626f6b9c-2681-3ad9-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Hilpert Group",
        "Logo": "/tmp/aa142bb879e8a03df8634e87cb2e5f5e.jpg",
        "Address": "9193 Funk Alley\nMcCluretown, MO 03610-2601",
        "Zip": "32091",
        "City": "New Karentown",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "ec29c579-f6de-3d58-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Conroy-McKenzie",
        "Logo": "/tmp/275dac535cb9ce031faee19309363ad5.jpg",
        "Address": "906 Shirley Wall Suite 397\nO\'Reillyfort, AL 85503-2410",
        "Zip": "49532-",
        "City": "Lake Oletaport",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "39dad66c-e399-319a-b"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Kris, Schoen and Orn",
        "Logo": "/tmp/9ca37b175c49e2a786afc747659d91c9.jpg",
        "Address": "41106 Amelia Locks\nLavinaburgh, DC 59553",
        "Zip": "75767",
        "City": "South Melyssaside",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "115e3932-12b4-3fb4-b"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Zemlak, Wuckert and Rosenbaum",
        "Logo": "/tmp/635c51a3cc0de11289c2997a8eba0347.jpg",
        "Address": "99847 Stiedemann Estates Suite 623\nWest Korymouth, HI 41991-1801",
        "Zip": "61771",
        "City": "Justicebury",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "9f2a79b9-b353-3c09-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Bogisich, Stokes and O\'Conner",
        "Logo": "/tmp/37f259657a82c06a96affba1ac8f7940.jpg",
        "Address": "240 Mariane Rapid\nWest Effie, WA 73757-8372",
        "Zip": "26105",
        "City": "Port Caden",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "f27b4b43-d964-3ef0-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Swift and Sons",
        "Logo": "/tmp/28b2223c1bb990dfb0a072054f900a9d.jpg",
        "Address": "318 Maybelle Turnpike\nSchaefermouth, OK 59036",
        "Zip": "44838",
        "City": "Homenickmouth",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "3ce903d4-10b3-3c9d-9"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Gleichner, Mosciski and Donnelly",
        "Logo": "/tmp/fd7e0af605193766fc1f1da598886f49.jpg",
        "Address": "922 Dariana Club Apt. 822\nEast Mireille, NY 88400-0249",
        "Zip": "89335-",
        "City": "Hortensefort",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "05b2ed89-3568-3478-a"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Schiller-Conroy",
        "Logo": "/tmp/37ad9c0d3946b50668e916ed7e5192a0.jpg",
        "Address": "4251 Mariah Knoll\nPort Shanelburgh, MT 37153-6153",
        "Zip": "37923",
        "City": "Ronaldochester",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "058cd122-60e3-31fd-8"
      },
      {
        "CompanyName": "Cartwright, Sanford and Morar",
        "Logo": "/tmp/cb9804f1dd41bfe137255a3fefd0264d.jpg",
        "Address": "204 Grover Roads Suite 203\nLake Hailee, HI 24534-2955",
        "Zip": "85590-",
        "City": "Ronside",
        "KvkNumber": null,
        "EcaboNumber": "cdc49e99-fb43-31e0-9"
      }
    ]
  ]
}';
          $companies = json_decode($dummy);
          dd($companies);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The second block of code fails the json validator.

Comment: I see what you are saying. My mistake. Yes the JSON format is invalid in the whole block. The smaller test sample in your answer passes the JSON validator but the complete string doesn't. The second block of JSON you posted also fails the validator.

Comment: Had you tested it? I make `$dummy` as string to decode it, by replace `'` to `\'`, you can change  opposite if needed.

Comment: Oh, I know what happened! @jamie post wrong format and I fix it in block 1, then he edit it. So i write block 2

Comment: @rome sorry about that! +1 for you :)